# How to include text decoration in background-clip: text; effect?

Tags: css, webkit

I am using `-webkit-background-clip: text,border` and `color: transparent` on an anchor tag and it seems the underline never becomes visible.

What I want is to include the text decoration in the background clipping.

Here is my CSS:

```css
.background-clip {
  background: url(images/index-background.jpg) repeat top center fixed;
  -webkit-background-clip: text,border;
  color: transparent;
}

.background-clip a {
  color: transparent;
}

.background-clip a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: underline; /* doesn't seem to do anything, I am having trouble finding definitive documentation on this */
}
```

And the related HTML:

```
<div class="background-clip"><a href="#">Imagine a lot of text here</a></div>
```

I am having a lot of trouble finding thorough documentation of the WebKit CSS properties. Does anyone know what I can do to make the text underline appear on hover of my anchor tag?

Comment: I don't know a solution, but in the [Mozilla tutorial for background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) they make it work somehow.

Comment: Also I just found this is tracked as a bug in webkit, with activity as of 2022: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=179334

Answer (score 2):

You can change your -webkit-text-fill-color to a RGBA value, like so; `-webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);` This allows the underline to display. Just play around with the opacity and rgb values to match the colour of your background etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this on Chrome 50.0 and Firefox Nightly 49.0a1 (which also supports `-webkit-background-clip: text` [since version 48.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759568))

And as far as I can see, [against the WebKit documentation](https://webkit.org/blog/164/background-clip-text/) there is no way to include the text decoration or the text shadows in the clipping.

According to a [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=269140) `-webkit-text-decorations-in-effect` targets to correct inheritance issues related to the standard `text-decoration` property, though it obviously doesn't affect `-webkit-background-clip: text` in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You actually get the underline, but it has a transparent color, too :)

Comment: But why doesn't it have the background clipped to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can show the `text-decoration` with `background-clip: text;`, but you can create your underline playing with some `css`.

```css
/* UNNECESSARY CSS */

body {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* NECESSARY CSS */
.link {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  pointer-events: all;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, green 50%, #43b843ff 50%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  transition: background-position 150ms ease;
}
.link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
  transition: width 150ms ease;
}
.link:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
  color: green;
}
.link:hover:after {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="link">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Andrew,

You can't see underline if you use color:transparent. Try below code, you will see underline on hover.

```
    .background-clip {
     background:url(images/index-background.jpg) repeat top center fixed;
    -webkit-background-clip: text,border;
     color: transparent;}

    .background-clip a {
     color:red;
    text-decoration:none;}

    .background-clip a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    -webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: underline;}`
```

Comment: What I want is the background to clip to the underline as well as the text.  -webkit-background-clip:text pretty much skins an image over the text, when the color is also set to Transparent, its a pretty cool effect.