# Missing underline for <a href> and <u>

Tags: html, css

I have the following section of code:

```
    echo "<form>
          <div id=\"error\"align=\"center\">";
    echo "You've either key-ed in the wrong <b>username</b> or wrong <b>password</b>. <br/>";
    echo "Please contact person in-charged or click <u><a href=\"login.php\">here</a></u> to login again.";
    echo "</div></form>";
```

and the corresponding CSS:

```
#error{
font-family: "Acens", Verdana, Tahoma;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #2f4f4f);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
body {
    display:table;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
form {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:240px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

The output:

[image]

And shown in the image, there isnt any underline at `here` which was expected. However, it still able to direct user to another page.

Comment: Somewhere in your css you are setting the text-decoration to none

Comment: why are you adding the <u> tag.  <a href...>link</a> should underline it for you.

Comment: You should add `text-decoration:underline;` to your CSS for `#error a`

Comment: @PatsyIssa: I've scanned thru the document, I'm afraid that's not the case

Comment: @Scorpion: Isn't that by defauly there will be an underline for `a href`? Why do I have to do it externally?

Comment: @IsaacLem it could be it was being overridden. Can you give us a link?

Comment: can u give us the url??? we can test it and let u know!

Comment: It's on local machine I'm sorry

Comment: or if it's not on the web, try using a web inspector in chrome or safari or whatever browser you're using. It will tell you exactly what is being overridden.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @wetjosh: Google Chrome

Comment: Its because of the `-webkit-background-clip`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131807/webkit-background-clip-for-links-with-underline

Comment: @user1576573: YES! Bingo! Please make it as your answer! Nice!

Comment: Glad we managed to get it working. I will amend my previous answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because of `-webkit-background-clip`

[How to include text decoration in background-clip: text; effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131807/webkit-background-clip-for-links-with-underline)

Comment: it will at least let you know if it is a precedence issue

Comment: yes, true. I am sure there is a declaration of text-decoartion: none somewhere. May be @Isaac is using a third party stylesheet.

Comment: @user1576573: I've scan thru line by line in my style sheet and made sure there is no `text-decoration:none` and your way doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

What if you try to manually set the underline in the css

```
 a {
     text-decoration: underline
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

add a style

```
a:link {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

to your stylesheet. Like @patsy says, somewhere you've removed it. And put it at the end of the stylesheet to be safe (so that if comes after the rule where it was removed).

Comment: Tried, still doesn't appear

Answer (score 2):

Add this style

```
#error a {
    text-decoration:underline !important; //override
}
```

Comment: `!important` must occur before the semicolon.

Comment: @str: even put the `!important` before the semicolon still doesn't work

Comment: sorry, typo check now @str

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an issue with the custom font you are using, *Acens*.

Try using an alternative method, a sort of "hack" - Add this to your CSS:

```
#error a{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Nice try, it is showing the border but it doesn't looks like an underline and it's extremely ugly haha. So maybe custom font will somehow remove the underline?

Comment: @IsaacLem I think it's possible the font may cause the issue, try changing to an `Arial` see if the underline appears. And using CSS properties such as `padding` and `width` will help you make the border-bottom look like a real underline :)